# Is there a way to connect existing Angular app to another nativescript app(angular)?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to initiate a call from Angular Web App and redirect it to Nativescript app, make the call and return the call duration back to Angular Web App. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Actually my website is on Angular and I want to initiate a phone call from there and redirect to nativescript app and get call details such as call duration and call audio recording and send this back to angular website.

Comment: From my understanding of browser security and access between two websites, it would contradict the principles. If the native app publishes the values ​​itself and determines them using a web crawl, you could try it. But I think there would have to be a server in between, on which the native app writes and the Angular app reads.

Comment: Can't it be just like redirecting the website to app and sending phone number via query param?

Comment: Maybe, for me the arrangement sounds a bit weird. If you have access to code and deployment to the native app, why not implement your requirements there? Otherwise, why do you need this information on a different websites...

Comment: I have my entire application built on Angular. It's already up and running. But now, I want to get phone call duration and phone call recording. That's the reason nativescript came into picture. I hope I was clear?